# Ruby - Remotely connecting to Mongodb on EC2

Tags: ruby, mongodb, amazon-ec2

I've outgrown localhost and have no idea how to connect to my EC2 server remotely.
`MongoClient.new('ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com', 27017, pool_timeout: 300)` does not work, and most documentation I've seen relates to setting up clusters.

Even though it's not recommended: I've even edited the security params to accept all TCP/UDP/ICMP connections, and still receive the `: Failed to connect to a master node at ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:27017 (Mongo::ConnectionFailure)` error.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon-ec2/ All the basics work, including being able to access the mongoDB shell? Just no remote access?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the security group of the mongodb instance allows the instance with your ruby app to connect to port 27017.